# Trying to get taxonomy link from another custom post

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm listing all movies on custom post type 'listing' and all directors listing on custom post type 'directors' when i trying to get taxonomy link for movie directors its display nothing.

```
<?php

$taxonomy ='mydirectors';
$term_lists = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);
foreach ($term_lists as $termlist):
    $name_term= $termlist->slug;
    $argsdirectors = array(
        'post_type' => 'directors',
        'name' => $name_term
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query($argsdirectors);
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
        while($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
    ?>  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">   <?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'mydirectors' );
    if ( $terms != null ){
        print ' <div class="detail"><span class="name"><font size="+1">Director</font></span><br />';
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            print $term->name."<br>" ;
            unset($term);
            if (!empty($terms)) {
                echo "";
            }
        }
        print "</div><br>";
    } 
    ?></a>
    <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried echoing $post->ID and seeing what it outputs? I suspect your problem lies there.

Comment: Thanks for your response but its not solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing $post->ID with get_the_ID() like this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID() , 'mydirectors' );
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

Comment: Thank you so much! I have try this and its not solve my problem :(

Comment: How about using echo instead of print?

Comment: I did, but not solve the problem. :( if i replace a text in <a> tags instead of php code which get taxonomy name,  it's still not working.